# Хранение некоторых опций компилятора в исходном коде и их получение gnumake

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnumake

Идея состоит в хранении некоторых опций компиляции в виде комментариев в начале компилируемых Си файлов, в процессе сборки они, при их наличии, должны вычленяться, **средствами GNUmake**, из собираемого файла и передаваться компилятору.

Но что то не найду подходящего инструментария, может есть какие-то хитрые приёмы?

Задачи по сути две:
1. Построчное чтение **средствами gnumake**, несколько первых строк файла.
2. Парсинг - вычленение опций по маркерам из найденной строки.

UPD: хочется реализовать платформонезависимую возможность использовать опции компиляции хранящиеся в виде комментариев в коде. Что-то вроде

```
/* 
 * CCFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
 */
```

В таком случае, в Makefile будут находиться только общие для проекта опции сборки.

Ограничения, сделать требуется всё средствами gnumake, как сделать иными средствами знаю. PS: Внешние вызовы, например $(shell ...), не использовать.

Какие будут идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условно говоря, решение найдено, пришлось немного нарушить собственное требование не использовать функцию $(shell ), но это допустимое отступление, т.к. использовался GCC которым и производится сборка, т.е. без gcc нет смысла и в получении флагов.

Итак, костылёное решение:
создаём Си файл следующего содержания

```
#ifdef GET_FLAGS
#error CCFLAGS:-02:-pthread:-D_REENTERANT
#error LDFLAGS:-02:-lthread:-lm
#endif

int main(void)
{

return(0);
}
```

Сразу видны костыли:
1. Флаги разделены двоеточиями, а не пробелами
2. Флаги обёрнуты в ifdef
3. предваряются директивой error

Вот Makefile который вытаскивает эти флаги и размещает их в своих внутренних переменных:

```
sources := $(wildcard *.c)

all : build_flags
        @:

func_builds_flagss = $(shell $(CC) -E -MM $(1) -DGET_FLAGS 2>&1)

define func_builds_flags
$(1)-TMP := $$(shell $(CC) -E -MM $(1) -DGET_FLAGS 2>&1)
$(1)-CCFLAGS := $$(subst :, ,$$(subst CCFLAGS:,,$$(word 1,$$(filter CCFLAGS:%,$$($(1)-TMP)))))
$(1)-LDFLAGS := $$(subst :, ,$$(subst LDFLAGS:,,$$(word 1,$$(filter LDFLAGS:%,$$($(1)-TMP)))))

$(1)-get_flags :
        @echo CC $(1) = $$($(1)-CCFLAGS)
        @echo LD $(1) = $$($(1)-LDFLAGS)
endef

$(foreach file,$(sources),$(eval $(call func_builds_flags,$(file))))

build_flags : $(patsubst %,%-get_flags,$(sources))
        @:
```

Кратко: вызываем gcc получаем строки с ошибками, из них вытаскиваем флаги, т.к. в gnumake парсер строк слабый, применён костыль с двоеточиями.

Comment: А стоит ли такое городить? Может все же лучше просто и прямо, не лениться и  без затей прописать все нужные флаги в Makefile (в соответствии с пожеланиями автора в комментариях в своих .c)

Comment: Как говориться, не нравится, не ешьте. Компилировать сложные проекты можно и без make, прямо в консоли набирать gcc ....

Comment: Посмотрите, как он Вам самому через пяток лет (и десяток уже никак не связанных с этим проектов)  понравится...

Comment: @avp Хоть это уже флуд, но Linux сколько уже лет собирается командой make?

Comment: При чем тут Linux? Не, ежели Вы в самом деле ежедневно пишете makefie, то это одно дело, а если раз в полгода, то совсем другое. Просто бывает смотришь через несколько лет на такой вот свой же "шедевр" и мучительно вспоминаешь, а как же оно работало? / И как известно -- лучшая программа эта та, которую сейчас пишешь.

Comment: @avp посмотрите на содержимое Mkefile-ов Linux и поймёте. Документируйте свои "Шедевры", тогда они не будут со временем превращаться в говнокод.

Answer (score 0):

насколько мне известно, **средствами программы *make*** (в любой из распространённых реализаций) требуемое осуществить невозможно.

---

немного подробней.

как я понял, имеется в виду не «хранение опций компиляции» (такая сущность отсутствует в программе *make*, ведь она не является компилятором или чем-то подобным), а присвоение значений переменным.

значения переменным можно присваивать в отдельных файлах, которые потом можно подключать в обрабатываемый **makefile* с помощью директивы *include*.

мало того, имя файла (и путь к нему) может формироваться на основе других переменных.

но, в любом случае, содержимое такого файла должно иметь синтаксис языка, используемого программой *make*. если файл представляет собой исходный текст на каком-либо ином языке программирования, то в подавляющем большинстве случаев (см. ниже пример возможного исключения) попытка его подключения с помощью директивы *include* завершится ошибкой.

---

пример «совместимого» синтаксиса:

```
var1=0
var2="текст"
```

такой файл «поймёт» и программа *make*, и *posix*-совместимая оболочка, и, наверно, ещё много других компиляторов, интерпретаторов и т.п. программ.

Comment: Дополнительно подключаемые файлы не нужны, опции можно прописать и в Makefile, хочется реализовать платформонезависимую возможность использовать опции компиляции. Что-то вроде `/* CCFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 */` В таком случае, в Makefile будут находиться только общие для проекта опции сборки.

Comment: @dsnk, повторю: программа make не имеет ни малейшего представления об опциях компиляции. просто потому, что она **не занимается** компиляцией. упрощённо говоря, она сначала строит дерево зависимостей (между целями), потом определяет, какие из целей требуют обновления, и, наконец, выполняет команды, приведённые в *\*makefile*, для обновления этих целей.

Comment: присвоение значений переменным происходит на первом шаге (при построении дерева зависимостей).

Comment: Повторю ещё раз, мне требуется вытащить из файла с исходным кодом его опции компиляции и передать компилятору, средствами gnumake.

Comment: Дерево зависимостей, можно строить динамически [см `$(eval )`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html)

Comment: @dsnk, нет ни в одной из известных мне реализаций программы make возможности «прочитать» *часть* файла.

Comment: @dsnk, и даже функция *eval* не поможет вам прочитать часть файла.

Comment: не выдумывайте, где я говорил что с её помощью можно читать файлы?

Comment: @dsnk, это был сарказм.

Comment: флудите в другом месте.

Comment: @dsnk, резюмирую: насколько мне известно, без привлечения сторонних программ желаемое вами — неосуществимо. если вам (вдруг) удастся осуществить желаемое, дайте мне знать, пожалуйста. я поставил вопрос в закладки, поэтому специально оповещать меня не нужно. напишите новый ответ: столь интересное решение будет наверняка полезно многим людям.